# Performing a health check in .NET Core Worker Service

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, service

How can I implement health checks in a .NET Core Worker Service?

The service will be run inside Docker and needs to be able to check the health of the service.

Answer (score 14):

Another way of doing this is to implement `IHealthCheckPublisher`.

The benefits of this approach is the ability to re-use your existing `IHealthCheck`s or integration with 3rd party libraries that rely on `IHealthCheck` interface (like [this one](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks)).

Though you still target `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` as the SDK you don't need to add any asp.net specifics.

Here is an example:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
  return Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
      services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck<RedisHealthCheck>("redis_health_check")
        .AddCheck<RfaHealthCheck>("rfa_health_check");

      services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, HealthCheckPublisher>();
      services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
      {
        options.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        options.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
      });
    });
}

public class HealthCheckPublisher : IHealthCheckPublisher
{
  private readonly string _fileName;
  private HealthStatus _prevStatus = HealthStatus.Unhealthy;

  public HealthCheckPublisher()
  {
    _fileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnvVariableNames.DOCKER_HEALTHCHECK_FILEPATH) ??
                Path.GetTempFileName();
  }

  public Task PublishAsync(HealthReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    // AWS will check if the file exists inside of the container with the command
    // test -f $DOCKER_HEALTH_CHECK_FILEPATH

    var fileExists = _prevStatus == HealthStatus.Healthy;

    if (report.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
    {
      if (!fileExists)
      {
        using var _ = File.Create(_fileName);
      }
    }
    else if (fileExists)
    {
      File.Delete(_fileName);
    }

    _prevStatus = report.Status;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this provided some very good inspiration to my solution! https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069909/1537195 I removed `if (!fileExists)` so that the file gets touched every time so k8s can actually check the last modified time (in case the app froze)

Answer (score 13):

I don't think is worth it to change SDK to **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web**. You will include additional middlewares just because of one health check? No thanks ...

What you could do is to use a different protocol like TCP.

The general idea is:

1. Create a separate background service that creates a TCP server (take a look at [TcpListener.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-5.0))
2. When you receive a request you have two options: if the application is healthy accept TCP connection otherwise reject it.
3. If you use containers your orchestrator should have an option to call it over TCP (in k8s there is a property [tcpSocket](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/))

If you need more detailed information you may check: [Monitoring Health of ASP.NET Core Background Services With TCP Probes on Kubernetes](https://dzone.com/articles/monitoring-health-of-aspnet-core-background-servic)

Cheers!

Comment: I think this is the most elegant approach without using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web while using Kubernetes. You can even have two different TCP ports open, one for _live_ and one for _ready_ endpoints.

Comment: One thing people should know is that for .net 7, they should use the `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` package. From here, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/

Answer (score 10):

Add HTTPListener and expose the health checks endpoints.

Using HTTPListener does not require adding Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK.

Program.cs

```
    using Consumer;
    
    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            services.AddHostedService<HttpHealthcheck>();
        })
        .Build();
    
    await host.RunAsync();
```

HttpHealthcheck.cs

```
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Consumer;
    
    public class HttpHealthcheck : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly HttpListener _httpListener;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    
    
        public HealthcheckHttpListener(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpListener = new HttpListener();
        }
    
    
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
    
            _httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:5001/healthz/live/");    
            _httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:5001/healthz/ready/");
    
            _httpListener.Start();
            _logger.LogInformation($"Healthcheck listening...");
    
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                HttpListenerContext ctx = null;
                try
                {
                    ctx = await _httpListener.GetContextAsync();
                }
                catch (HttpListenerException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.ErrorCode == 995) return;
                }
    
                if (ctx == null) continue;
    
                var response = ctx.Response;
                response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                response.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "no-store, no-cache");
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    
                var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Healthy");
                response.ContentLength64 = messageBytes.Length;
                await response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                response.OutputStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what  services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); is doing?

Comment: In my case, it is the implementation of Kafka consumer. You can read more about worker services here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should also consider to retain the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker.

Don't change the whole sdk just because of the health checks.

Then  you can create a backgroundservice (just like the main worker), in order to update a file to write for example the current timestamp. An example of the background health check worker would be:

```
public class HealthCheckWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly int _intervalSec;
    private readonly string _healthCheckFileName;

    public HealthCheckWorker(string healthCheckFileName, int intervalSec)
    {
        this._intervalSec = intervalSec;
        this._healthCheckFileName = healthCheckFileName;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(this._healthCheckFileName, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(this._intervalSec * 1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add a extension method like this:

```
public static class HealthCheckWorkerExtensions
{
    public static void AddHealthCheck(this IServiceCollection services,
        string healthCheckFileName, int intervalSec)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<HealthCheckWorker>(x => new HealthCheckWorker(healthCheckFileName, intervalSec));
    }
}
```

With this you can add in services the health check support

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHealthCheck("hc.txt", 5);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

What I've done to accomplish this is add Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web to my Worker, and then configured a web host to run alongside the worker:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddLogging(builder =>
            builder
                .AddDebug()
                .AddConsole()
        );
    });
```

With that done, all that's left to do is [map the health check endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as you normally would with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Will this report the faulty thread of the worker service? I mean suppose the worker service is unable to perform a task due to unhandled exception and stuck, whereas the /health endpoint don't consider it rather always respond 200ok as it is running in a different thread all together.

Comment: No, you would have to somehow detect from the health check that the service has stopped responding. Maybe a heart beat from the worker, but even then, I've seen cases where it's not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid HTTP approaches; just `touch` a file inside the container, and run a file-based health check - which works nicely with plain docker, or an orchestrator.

Create a hosted service to periodically touch the file `/tmp/myapp-healthcheck`:

```cs
public class FileBasedHealthCheckGenerator : BackgroundService {

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      Touch("/tmp/myapp-healthcheck");
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), stoppingToken);
    }
  }

  private void Touch(string path)
  {
    using var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(path, DateTime.UtcNow);
  }

}
```

Register the hosted service in `Program.cs`:

```cs
services.AddHostedService<FileBasedHealthCheckGenerator>();
```

Update the `Dockerfile`:

```
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=10s --interval=30s --timeout=10s --retries=3 \
  CMD [ $(find '/tmp/myapp-healthcheck' -mmin 0.5 | wc -l) -eq 1 ] || exit 1
```

Or update the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
healthcheck:
  start_period: 10s
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  test: '[ $(find '/tmp/myapp-healthcheck' -mmin 0.5 | wc -l) -eq 1 ] || exit 1'
```

Or update the orchestrator config.

That will touch `/tmp/myapp-healthcheck` every 30 seconds (`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)`). When the docker healthcheck runs it tries to find a matching file that was created/updated within the last 30s (`-mmin 0.5`).

That is the bare minimum implementation. One can add error handling, and extract the path and period into config settings to make it more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I run the following code in my worker process. In my opinion, it has the following advantages over some of the other solutions described here:

- It includes full production-ready code.
- It fails the health check reliably if the worker process is not healthy.

  - i.e. [@Veikedo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722982/1200847) seems to rely on the existance of a file. If the worker process crashes completly, the file might still exist. Thus, the health check passes even though the process does not even exist anymore.
- It fully relies on the `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` infrastructure and does not use any custom hosted services.
- Thus, it incorporates the health information that might be provided by many [add-in health checks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks).
- It does not involve any opened ports/TCP listeners/HTTP servers or other network interaction.
- This answer includes instructions how to set-up the health checks in your `Dockerfile` (credits [@lonix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77317290/1200847)).

First, create a `FileHealthCheckPublisher` class.

> Note that I'm using [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime)'s IClock interface to make this testable. You could easily remove the IClock dependency and write `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(path, DateTime.UtcNow);` instead. See also [@lonix's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77317290/1200847) answer.

```cs
internal sealed class FileHealthCheckPublisher : IHealthCheckPublisher
{
    private readonly IClock _clock;
    private readonly string _healthCheckFilePath = "/healthz";

    public FileHealthCheckPublisher(IClock clock)
    {
        _clock = clock;
    }

    public Task PublishAsync(HealthReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (report.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
        {
            Touch(_healthCheckFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            Delete(_healthCheckFilePath);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void Touch(string path)
    {
        using var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var now = _clock.GetCurrentInstant();
        File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(path, now.ToDateTimeUtc());
    }

    private void Delete(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        catch
        {
            // best effort delete; might not exist in the first place
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add this line to your Dockerfile

> I filter for files touched in the last 0.6s instead of 0.5s, as [@lonix's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77317290/1200847) answer does, to avoid the possible edge case that the check succeeded but was exactly 30s ago.

```
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=10s --interval=30s --timeout=10s --retries=3 \
  CMD [ $(find '/healthz' -mmin 0.6 | wc -l) -eq 1 ] || exit 1
```

Finally, register the services in your `Program.cs`/`Startup.cs`/DI config. Add those checks that are relevant for your use case. I use [Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore/) here. The community collection [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) might be interesting too.

```cs
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddDbContextCheck<AppDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, FileHealthCheckPublisher>();
```

See also: [Microsoft Docs on *Health checks in ASP.NET Core*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks)

I took much inspiration from [@Veikedo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722982/1200847) and [@lonix's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77317290/1200847) answers, thanks!